# Codeigniter: display two data in query with distinct and count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm try to display two data of one query using codeigniter.

```
$query = "SELECT  count(distinct p.id_paciente), count(c.pacientes_id_paciente) FROM paciente p, cita c WHERE p.id_paciente=c.pacientes_id_paciente AND p.usuarios_id_usuario=43 AND p.aseguradoras_id_aseguradora=8 AND c.dia_cita>='2015-04-16' AND c.dia_cita<='2015-04-16'";

    $sql = $this->db->query($query);
```

How can I to show the two results of count(distinct p.id_paciente) and the count(c.pacientes_id_paciente)

I try using

```
foreach ($sql->result_array() as $row)
```

{

```
echo $row['id_paciente'];

echo $row['pacientes_id_paciente'];
```

}

But only display the content of the array...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Use aliases to name columns in the resultset to be able to address them later by name

```sql
    SELECT  COUNT(distinct p.id_paciente) AS count1, ...
                                             ^^^^^^
```

2. Don't interpolate query strings yourself. Use Codeigniter's query bindings
3. This may not be relevant to you but if `dia_cita` has time component to it (i.e. is of type `datetime`) you may want to change your `WHERE` condition to

```sql
    c.dia_cita >= ? AND c.dia_cita < ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

4. There is no need for `foreach` loop. You always get only one row with this query. Therefore use Codeigniter's `row()` or `row_array()`.

That being said your code may look like

```php
$sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_paciente) AS count1, 
           COUNT(c.pacientes_id_paciente) AS count2 
      FROM paciente p JOIN cita c 
        ON p.id_paciente = c.pacientes_id_paciente
     WHERE p.usuarios_id_usuario = ? 
       AND p.aseguradoras_id_aseguradora = ? 
       AND c.dia_cita >= ? 
       AND c.dia_cita < ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY
";

$bindings = array(43, 8, '2015-04-16', '2015-04-16')

$row = $this->db
    ->query($sql, $bindings)
    ->row_array();

echo $row['count1'], $row['count2'];
```